# Older style code language declarations no longer work

Tags: support

Today I discovered that the HTML markup language declarations for code blocks no longer work. They are still described in the [advanced markup help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting), though.

Is this a bug in the documentation or the implementation?

Examples,

1. Triple backticks. Using a language tag here does work (but not on Meta). Literal:

   ````
   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash
   [ -d '.' ] && echo "My directory is $PWD"
   ```
   ````

   And the corresponding rendered text:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   [ -d '.' ] && echo "My directory is $PWD"
   ```
2. Older style HTML comment. Also doesn't work on Meta, used to work on U&L but does no longer. Literal:

   ```
   <!--language: lang-bash-->
       #!/bin/bash
       [ -d '.' ] && echo "My directory is $PWD"
   ```

   And the corresponding rendered text:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   [ -d '.' ] && echo "My directory is $PWD"
   ```

---

Here is a screenshot from U&L to illustrate the rendering behaviour

[image: Text rendered as on Unix&Linux]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just missing a couple of spaces. It should be:

```
<!-- language: lang-bash -->

    #!/bin/bash
    [ -d '.' ] && echo "My directory is $PWD"
```

[image]

Note that the documentation does have spaces after `<!--` and before `-->`.